# Barcode image encoding works on simulator but not device

Tags: ios, objective-c, zxing, cgimageref

Im using ZXing framework to make an barcode image out of a string. When i try it on the simulator it work, but when I try it on a device, I get a bad access error

```
ZXMultiFormatWriter *writer = [ZXMultiFormatWriter writer];
    ZXBitMatrix* result = [writer encode:self.discountProgramInfo.customerID
                                  format:self.barcodeFormat
                                   width:self.barcodeImageView.frame.size.width
                                  height:self.barcodeImageView.frame.size.height
                                   error:&error];
    if (result) {

        CGImageRef image = [[ZXImage imageWithMatrix:result] cgimage];
        self.barcodeImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
        // This CGImageRef image can be placed in a UIImage, NSImage, or written to a file.
    } else {
        NSString *errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
        DLog("%@",errorMessage);
    }
```

It fails on this line: `self.barcodeImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];` and the `CGImageRef` is not generated properly.

Any ideas what could be causing the mismatch?

Comment: The function encode:format:width:height:error: takes an NSError parameter by reference. Have you checked the error?

Comment: Also, how can you both crash with a bad access ERROR and have the CGImageRef not created properly? If your app crashes, how can you see if the image ref is generated or not?

Comment: Because I put a break point when its created, but before I use it.when inspecting the CGImageRef(using the little eye icon that pops up when you hover) On the simulator I get a nice picture of a barcode, on the device I get a picture of nothing.  The error is empty.

Comment: But I thought you said you crash with a bad access error? Once your app crashes, the values in your app's variables are not trustworthy.

Comment: It crashes on self.barcodeImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image]; I inspect the image one step before, right after creation

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere. Is the CGImageRef == NULL?  You should probably add code to check the CGImageRef for NULL before passing it to `imageWithCGImage:`

Comment: That's the thing, its not null, just unImagable or something. I will retrace some of my steps and post a followup

Comment: @DuncanC After some checking, I made sure the error is indeed nil, and the CGImageRef has some value, when I log the result, it looks like a a barcode. I'm running out of ideas what could be going wrong.